# How do one check with Php if a file is genuinely Editable

Tags: php

How do one check with php if a file is 'genuinely' editable i.e. the file is editable in any file editor. Ex : php, text, html or even .htaccess file. All these file is editable in notepad or any text editor.

I am using php 'is_writable' function. But it is also returning image file as writable file.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "editable" with "text". I can open an image file in Photoshop and edit it quite happily, for that matter I could [do it with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) too.

Comment: Aren't **ALL** files technically editable? I could open a .png file in notepad and edit it no problem.. the result wouldn't be good, but I can still edit it.

Comment: @Chris — Not if they are marked as read only

Comment: Sorry, let me correct it, it should be text